# Filtering queries in BreezeJS apps that don't use Entity Framework on the server

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to adapt the approach taken in the Breeze **NoDb** sample app and hook it into an existing application's back-end which does not use Entity Framework (it instead has existing Business Objects which I am trying to reuse).

I'm struggling with trying to understand how best to translate queries received by the controller into calls to my Business Objects to fetch/save data and also, how to optimize these queries.

Currently in the NoDb sample app the `TodoContext` class on the server acts an in-memory database of `TodoList` objects and it surfaces those objects through the `TodoRepository` class to the `TodoController`. The `TodoController` then exposes this list as a single `IQueryable<TodoList> TodoList()` action. This allows the client to pass odata filter criteria to the server and return a filtered collection of `TodoList` (items if they specify the odata search filters). I believe this all happens auto-magically thanks to the BreezeController.

Now, let's assume you have a HUGE number of `TodoList`'s stored in some form of data store (*e.g. existing business objects, non-sql db, mongo db, xml file, etc...*) and I want to avoid loading them all from the store into an in-memory object just to be able to return the filtered results to the client.

How would you use the filter criteria available in the client request to reduce the amount of data being fetched out of the data store on the server? For example, I want to retrieve a collection of `TodoList` items that have any `TodoItem` that contains 'buy milk', but I don't want to have to load every `TodoList` and all of their detail items into memory to find out. I would rather translate the odata filter criteria into a native data store query (or in my case a call to my existing Business Object).

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks!
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most third party datastores available on .NET provide an IQueryable implementation.  If you return the base dataStore IQueryable for each resource, then the breeze server will compose a composite IQueryable ( composed of your base IQueryable and any client side filters applied), and send this to your datastore.  This means that the fully composed query is what is executed by your datastore.

We are hoping to have a MongoDb or a RavenDb sample within the next month or so, that demonstrates this.